# Dice Program Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple Dice program. I want to increment sum variable and print amount won every time a player wins.Thanks in advance

```
import random as rm 
def gamble():
     dice= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
     x=input('what is the number ')
     x=int(x)
     secure_random = rm.SystemRandom()
     y=int(secure_random.choice(dice))
     print(y)
     sum=0
     while x==y :
         sum=sum+50
         print("You Won ",sum)
         break
    for i in range(20):
      gamble()
```

Comment: check the values you are trying to compare, mostly, check their type

Comment: `y` is `None` because `print(...)` returns `None` so it'll never be equal. Print it first then check... Also... where the numbers do match, you'll have an infinite loop and keep printing "You Won 50$" - I'm fairly sure you don't want that. When in doubt (like @PRMoureu says) - printing everything so you can see what's going on makes these things more obvious and is an important and easy technique while learning.

Comment: Venkata, if my answer solved your problem please click the green checkmark to indicate that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out of your loop.

```
while x == y:
    print("You Won 50$")
    break
```

That said, a `while` loop is a bad way to do this.
I would use an `if` statement:

```
if x == y:
    print("You Won 50$")
```

Then no `break` is needed.

Additionally, don't set anything equal to print, and make the values the same type.

```
curSum = 50
def gamble():
   global curSum
   dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
   x = input('what is the number ')
   x = int(x)
   secure_random = rm.SystemRandom()
   y = int(secure_random.choice(dice))
   print(y)
   if x == y :
       # Change + 1 to whatever amount you want to add
       curSum = curSum + 1
       print("You Won %d $" % curSum)
   for i in range(3):
       gamble()
```

Comment: How to sum amount. for example instead of printing  'You won 50$' . I want to increment value of variable sum everytime the player wins

Comment: local variable 'curSum' referenced before assignment - I am getting this error

Comment: Yeah you're right, I forgot the `global`.  Fixed accordingly.